# nested if help cant read statement excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

can you help me out. It can't write "moderate" or can't read the logic in the middle one where the "moderate" statement is located

```
=IF(CA7=0,"none",IF(CA7=1<=7,"low",IF(CA7=8<=14,"moderate",IF(CA7>=15,"high"))))
```

Comment: it writes "FALSE"

Comment: =IF(CA7=0,"none",IF(CA7<=7,"low",IF(CA7<=14,"moderate","high")))

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
=IF(CA7=0,"none",IF(CA7<=7,"low",IF(CA7<=14,"moderate","high")))
```

The nested IF will stop after finding first TRUE condition, so you don't have to specify the lower range and upper range. The upper is enough.

Also this looks like a job for some Lookup function (VLOOKUP, MATCH + INDEX, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Try the below formula,

`=IF(CA7>=15,"High",IF(CA7>=8,"Moderate",IF(CA7>=1,"Low","None")))`

You want to start with the upper limit and then work your way down to the lower values. The lowest value should be the false.